# How to change SQL Server locale in docker

Tags: sql-server, docker

i am not able to change the default dateformat and lcid from the microsoft image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest

I would like to be able to set the sql server container to en_US, lcid 1034 and the dateformat to dmy.

I have a container up on the host machine with ubuntu 20.04 with the following locales

```
LANG=es_ES.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

el contenedor se levanta desde un docker-compose.yml con la siguiente configuración:

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  sqlserver:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
    container_name: sqlserver-dev-linux
    ports:
      - 1433:1433
    environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
      SA_PASSWORD: "Password"
      MSSQL_PID: "Developer"
      MSSQL_LCID: "1034"
    volumes:
        - './drive:/var/opt/mssql'
        - './media:/media'
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy `
```

y cuando voy a comprobar la configuración me devuelve:

```
Set Option                                                                        Value
----------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------------
textsize                                                                           4096
language                                                                     us_english
dateformat                                                                          mdy
datefirst                                                                             7
lock_timeout                                                                         -1
ansi_null_dflt_on                                                                   SET
ansi_warnings                                                                       SET
ansi_padding                                                                        SET
ansi_nulls                                                                          SET
concat_null_yields_null                                                             SET
isolation level
```

Any help is welcome, thank you, best regards.

Comment: Was the `MSSQL_LCID` environment variable added after the initial composition? It only applies on the container's first launch, after that you'll need to change it with the `mssql-conf` tool.

Comment: Yes, from the Dockerfile before a build or by this command: `docker exec -u root -it dc318adb656d /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf setup`. I receive the following error: ```Setting language using LCID from environment variable MSSQL_LCID
LCID 1034 is not supported.```